# Displaying PHP Code as Plaintext

Tags: php

I need to do something like this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo <<<EOT
<?php echo 'arbitrary code using ' . $variables . ' and such.'; 
echo 'finished';
?>
EOT;
```

The problem is, PHP still interprets the inline PHP as code and tries to execute it. I would like just to see the code printed in the window.

Comment: Heredoc syntax has the same variable substitution rules as double quoted strings. You could use Nowdoc syntax instead: `echo<<< 'EOT' ... EOT`

Comment: what is what you're getting shown and what is that what you want to print?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc), notice the quotes around `'EOT'`:

```
echo <<<'EOT'
<?php echo 'arbitrary code using ' . $variables . ' and such.'; 
echo 'finished';
?>
EOT;
```

Or use a [single quoted](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) string, obviously escaping single quotes in the string:

```
echo '
<?php echo \'arbitrary code using \' . $variables . \' and such.\'; 
echo \'finished\';
?>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `highlight_string` function, it receives a string containing your php code and outputs html with the syntax highlight colors.

ex:

```
<?php highlight_string("<?php echo 'hi'; ?>");?>
```

You have also the function `highlight_file`, same thing, but receives a string with the file location.

Doc:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php